# Python 2 Tkinter make labels fixed/stationary

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've a Tkinter-programm where I regularly (10 times/second) update Labels with certain sensor-values.

The problem is that they are arranged with .grid right next to each other and when a value gets/loses a place (e.g. 10 -> 9, 60 -> 150, you see the number needs extra space) the label jumps back and forth (because the number gains or loses a space and therefore .grid responds by adjusting the Label).

How can i avoid that? Do I need to change Text & Numbers to a certain font or is there a function that fixes the Labels place? I'd be happy about useful answers.

Here's a code example (please notice how the labels are adjusting cause that's the problem):

```
#!/usr/bin/env

import sys
import time
import subprocess
from Tkinter import *
import numpy
import random



i = 0
x = 0


def GetValue():
    x = random.randint(0,10000)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return x

def UebergabeTkinter():
    while 1:

        CompleteValue = GetValue()
        Variable1.set(CompleteValue)
        Variable2.set(CompleteValue)
        Variable3.set(CompleteValue)
        Variable4.set(CompleteValue)
        root.update()

def Exit():
    root.destroy()
    return


try:

    root = Tk()

    Leiste = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu = Leiste)

    DateiMenu = Menu(Leiste)
    Leiste.add_cascade(label = "datei", menu = DateiMenu)
    DateiMenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = Exit)

    EditMenu = Menu(Leiste)
    Leiste.add_cascade(label = "edit", menu = EditMenu)


    Variable1 = IntVar()
    Variable2 = IntVar()
    Variable3 = IntVar()
    Variable4 = IntVar()

    Ausgang = 0
    for column in range(0,8,2):
        String1 = "Ausgang "
        String1 += `Ausgang`
        Ausgang = Ausgang + 1
        Label(text = String1).grid(row=0,column=column)

    Ausgang = 0
    for column in range(0,8,2):
        String1 = "Der Wert von "
        String2 = " ist: "
        String1 += `Ausgang`
        Ausgang = Ausgang + 1
        String3 = String1+String2
        Label(text = String3).grid(row=2,column=column)

    Label1 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable1)
    Label1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    Label2 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable2)
    Label2.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    Label3 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable3)
    Label3.grid(row = 2, column = 5, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    Label4 = Label(root, textvariable = Variable4)
    Label4.grid(row = 2, column = 7, sticky = W+E+N+S)

    UebergabeTkinter()


    root.mainloop()



except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Hallo"
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: You'd need a AD/DA converter from waveshare and a sensor to run the Code.

Comment: So can you not even post a sample?

Comment: Give me a minute

Comment: Alright, hope that helps

Comment: Which mistakes?

Comment: I'm looking at it but I cannot spot the mistake. "Ausgang" is just defining the channel and prints aus "Ausgang 0", "Ausgang 1" and so on.

Comment: Oh, I was running it in python 3. sorry for that.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I forgot to mention that I'm not working with Python3 *facepalm*

Answer (score 3):

You can give labels a fixed width:

```
Label1 = Label(root, textvariable=Variable1, width=4)
```

Just make sure they are large enough to fit every number that could be put in, since of course next no the label not shrinking when the number is shorter, this also means that they will not grow to fit larger numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out and report back.